# How to make a plot to view SEM of two independent samples in a single plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I'm working with Confirmatory Factorial Analysis in a one-dimensional questionnaire and I want to generate a SEM plot. However the participants who answered the questionnaire are fluent in two languages, one group answered the questionnaire in language X and the other answered the same questionnaire in language Y. I want to create a single plot that shows the parameters of the two groups. As in this example:

[image: one-dimensional model with two intependent groups]

I can only create separate plots using R:

```
library(lavaan)
library(semPlot)

#data
GrupoX <- data[data$language == 1,25:34]
GrupoY <- data[data$language == 2,25:34]

#fitting
modelX <- " f1  =~ Item1 + Item2 + Item3 + Item4 + Item5 + Item6 + Item7 + Item8 + Item9 + Item10"
fitX <- lavaan(modelX, data = GrupoX, auto.var = TRUE, auto.fix.first=TRUE, auto.cov.lv.x=TRUE, estimator="ML")
modelY <- " f1  =~ Item1 + Item2 + Item3 + Item4 + Item5 + Item6 + Item7 + Item8 + Item9 + Item10"
fitY <- lavaan(modelX, data = GrupoY, auto.var = TRUE, auto.fix.first=TRUE, auto.cov.lv.x=TRUE, estimator="ML")

#plots
semPaths(fitX, what = "std", residuals = FALSE, nCharNodes = 0, edge.label.cex = 1, legend=F, rotation=2)
semPaths(fitY, what = "std", residuals = FALSE, nCharNodes = 0, edge.label.cex = 1, legend=F, rotation=2)
```

Could someone help me on how I could create a single plot with the information from each group? Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps `layout(t(1:2))` before using `semPaths` as the example suggested? Otherwise, we could try `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` before.

Comment: @Quar Thank you for your answer, your suggestion is very good! But I'd like to build a single plot that contains both information as in the image put as an example. The functions you suggested only return two plots on the side of each other, I'd like to make it a single plot. Is this possible?

Comment: does it help to add argument `combineGroups=T` into `semPaths()` ? Like `semPaths(fitX, what = "std", residuals = FALSE, nCharNodes = 0, edge.label.cex = 1, legend=F, rotation=2, combineGroups=T)`